# Two instances of enum array in jmap

Tags: java, enums, jmap

When I was analyzing the output of jmap from our application, I came across something strange with enum classes. For each enum, there were two instances of the enum array created. What does this array contain? Why are there two instances of the enum array created for each enum?

```
num     #instances      #bytes  class name
946:         2           8080  [Lcom.extsys.server.invalignment.InvAlignErrorCode;        
1454:        2           1920  [Lcom.extsys.server.import.ImportObjects$ImportResultType;
1657:        2           1232  [Lcom.extsys.telecom.Constants$ErrorCode;
```